# How to get the location type or how to identify if a given location it's a city, a state , a country after a location lookup with Google Places API?

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api, google-places

I'm using the Google Places API / Autocomplete to search for locations in my website. When the users searches for a location, a list of prediction is returned but I would like to categorize the results in the list by location type.

For example if the user searches for "New York" how I can tell if the location is a city or a state or a country. Is there a way to clearly know the location level/type in order to do something like in the example below (see image) ?

[image: Example Image - list of predictions categorized by location type]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types are available on the Google Places API /Autocomplete response on the "types" array:

Country = "types" : [ "country", "political", "geocode" ]

```
    {
                  "description" : "Italy", "id" : "25e96cea79a01f7308e93c44a0df106bb0f95e3f", 
                  "matched_substrings" : [ { "length" : 2, "offset" : 0 } ],
                  "place_id" : "ChIJA9KNRIL-1BIRb15jJFz1LOI",
                  "reference" : "CiQdAAAA70Hqa7YV7SeclW_Lfg1TB2s1o5aAk9j9iRn79CODJI4SEFgu3rYiXss6oQY1PKBniy8aFN5525fCHdYaSHfFcuK1jmf4tGiv",
                  "terms" : [ { "offset" : 0, "value" : "Italy" } ],
                  "types" : [ "country", "political", "geocode" ] 
                }
```

City = "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]

```
{ "description" : "Itingen, Switzerland", "id" : "d3caa11828d35eb13c066fa987a5859cf4dc8219", "matched_substrings" : [ { "length" : 2, "offset" : 0 } ], "place_id" : "ChIJo5eKUs7KkUcRdgR0wD1DONE", "reference" : "CjQsAAAAur4OIssVGpNZ68mQn4zwvkFWl2vqGEdJYpO1BVc9aUU8XtJ7uQyen-tPXaDGxf-3EhANsxjvPxzsAAGVyBzP0LPeGhREmHdg7PVMtfsodwFN0KO4z6hqDA", "terms" : [ { "offset" : 0, "value" : "Itingen" }, { "offset" : 9, "value" : "Switzerland" } ], "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ] }
```

And so on, there are other "types" provided by Google.